# How to set my username and password in the code.?

Tags: android, security

```
Button loginbuttonbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
loginbuttonbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(inputEmail.getText().toString() == "EdEffort@ncat.edu" &&
           inputPassword.getText().toString() == "Steelers") {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                                         Host_Setting_PageActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Username or password is incorrect");
        }
    }
});
```

That is my code and the application actually start but whenever I hit the login button the application closes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) ==> Use `.equals` instead of `==` to compare strings.

Comment: Everyday there is atleast 1 question on SO on string comparison.

Comment: @KazekageGaara - That's not unreasonable - it's an easy mistake to make, and the results don't often look like a string comparison error. For users coming from a language like C++ or C#, recognizing the error isn't in any way intuitive.

Comment: @derekerdmann yup. I know. That was just a follow up comment to the possible duplicate comment. I didn't mean to demoralize the OP in any way if that's what you thought it to be. :-)

Comment: @KazekageGaara Thats right but sometimes begginer dont know that how to compare string

Answer (score 3):

first use `.equals()` to compare strings.

`==` compares string refrences.Not value.

`.equals()` = compare strings character equality

```
if((inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("EdEffort@ncat.edu")&&inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("Steelers"))
```

And if force close than put logcat here..

Comment: I tried your way and it forced closed again, I put my Logcat above in your answer post

Answer (score 2):

use **equals** insead of **==** for String comparison

```
    loginbuttonbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("EdEffort@ncat.edu") && inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("Steelers") ){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(YOUR_CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this, Host_Setting_PageActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
            else{
                System.out.println("Username or password is incorrect");
            }
        }
    });
```

and make sure you are registering **YOUR_CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this** and **Host_Setting_PageActivity.class** both in manifest.xml

Comment: I attempted it your way also and the login screen still closes

Comment: can u post Logcat ? and i'm sure you have problem in Host_Setting_PageActivity.class Activity

Comment: Just posted logcat in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should add

Host_Setting_PageActivity.class to your AndroidManifest

And also, you should compare strings always using .equals and not with "==" as "==" will really compare the instance of the string object and .equals will check the value of the string

Answer (score 0):

dont use `== method` in if Condition but used `.equals()` method
like as

```
if(inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("abc") && inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("abc") ){
----------your code here-----------
}
```